# C# connect and query an existing MongoDb

Tags: c#, mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I'm trying to connect to my mongodb from C#. I'm not sure if I'm even actually connecting or not.

Here is the connection to my mongodb:

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:8081";
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var db = client.GetDatabase("nutchdatabase");
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("webpage");
```

I'm not sure on how to test to make sure I'm connected at all.

I also tried to query my db but I can't read the data to figure out if it worked or not. I tried following the tutorial [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/query/) but it didn't seem to help. Each reference I looked at involved creating a class for the fields in the db but i'm not sure what they will be since the db is already populated and fields can be added at random. Here is my code I currently have to query.

```
var filter = new BsonDocument();
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToJson();
```

I'm not sure if the  is even correct when declaring the collection variable but this is all I've gotten. If someone can help me get to the point where I know if I'm connected to the db and then get a successful query going I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Does the query work when you run it directly against the `MongoDB`?  What does your `Command Object` look like?  It seems to me that you haven't posted enough information for us to answer your question.

Comment: So I've run queries against the db in my mongo shell and it works. `db.webpage.find()` . I'm not sure what you mean by what my `Command Object` looks like.

Comment: This is what is in the variable result after execution, `{ \"_t\" : \"FindFluent`2\", \"Filter\" : { \"_t\" : \"BsonDocumentFilterDefinition`1\" } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with numerous methods from all over the internet I came across a post that seemed to help [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/273145/Using-MongoDB-with-the-Official-Csharp-Driver). Some said to add your connection string to Web.config file as:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MongoSessionServices" connectionString="mongodb:/localhost:27017" />
  <add name="DefaultMongoConnection" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
  <add key="MongoDbName" value="nutchdatabase"/>
</appSettings>
```

However this didn't work.

This is what DID work:

```
public static MongoServer GetConnection()
{
  //var cs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultMongoConnection"].ConnectionString;
  MongoServerSettings settings = new MongoServerSettings();
  settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("localhost", 27017);
  MongoServer server = new MongoServer(settings);
  return server;
}

public static MongoDatabase GetDatabase(string database = "")
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(database))
  {
    return GetConnection().GetDatabase(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MongoDbName"));
  }
  else
  {
    return GetConnection().GetDatabase(database);
  }
}
```

I was, however still able to use the Web.config file for the database name.

As far as the querying goes I figured that out as well. Here was my solution:

```
var db = GetDatabase();
var queryResults= db.GetCollection("webpage").FindAll().SetLimit(10000);
```

if I wanted all the urls in my db that had a html response code of 200 my query would be `var q1 = Query.EQ("status", 200);` then I'd pass the query to the Find() method like so `var statusOk = db.GetCollection("webpage").Find(q1);`. You then could iterate over each item in statusOk in a foreach loop.

Hope this helps someone in he future. (As a reference I'm using Visual Studio 2013, I'm writing this in a WebForms project, and I'm using version 2.6.9 of MongoDb)